# Why does my Lift Comet Actor stops working after deployment on Jetty?

Tags: scala, comet, lift

I'm playing around with Liftweb and its Comet support and I wrote some code which works fine on my local setup/computer. But as soon as I deploy the webapp to a production system (also Jetty), the CometActor is not doing anything. What is wrong with my code?

```
package code
package comet

import net.liftweb._
import http._
import net.liftweb.common.{Box, Full}
import net.liftweb.util._
import net.liftweb.actor._
import scala.language.postfixOps
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._
import net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmds.{SetHtml}
import net.liftweb.http.js.jquery.JqJsCmds.{PrependHtml}
import net.liftweb.http.js.JE.{Str}
import _root_.scala.xml.{Text, NodeSeq}
import org.apache.commons.io.input._

case class LogLine(str: String)

class MyTailerListener(logActor: LiftActor) extends TailerListenerAdapter {

    override def handle(line: String) { 
      logActor ! LogLine(line)   
    }
}

class CometLogEntry extends CometActor {

  val listener = new MyTailerListener(this)
  val tailer = Tailer.create(new java.io.File("/var/log/syslog"), listener)

  override def defaultPrefix = Full("log_entry") 

  def render = bind("newest" -> <span id="newest">No log enties yet!</span>)

  // Schedule an update every 5 seconds
  Schedule.schedule(this, LogLine, 5 seconds)

  override def lowPriority = {
    case LogLine(str:String) => {
      // Prepend the newest log line
      partialUpdate(PrependHtml("newest", <li style="list-style-type: none;">{str}</li>))
      Schedule.schedule(this, LogLine, 5 seconds)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the symptoms of the problem?  Errors?  Not updating? etc

Comment: @barnesjd I don't see any errors. At least the jetty log shows none. It's probably just not updating but it does perfectly on my development laptop.

Comment: Does the page initially contain the right data?  Or is it blank altogether?

Comment: On the server the page is just blank. I added some println and saw that the render method gets called one time but there's nothing to render at this time. Additionally, it seems that no CometActor is being started. I don't get any println info back from `lowPriority` method. On my local machine all this works and I get lot's of info back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but your implementation of `render` could potentially cause issues.  Render may be called at any time, not just when the CometActor is created.  It should result in an up-to-date view of the component.  In this case I'd either store the line you start your tail from so you can re-send the lines from that point or make your render function a NOOP.

Also, please use [CSS Selectors](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Binding_via_CSS_Selectors) instead of `bind` calls.

Comment: You mean storing the current line like this? This version works on my development laptop but not on the server. Too bad. `private var current = ""

    def getCurrent = current

    override def handle(line: String) {
      current = line
      logActor ! LogLine(line)   
    }`

My new `render` in `CometLogEntry`:

`def render = {
    if (listener.getCurrent != "") {
      "#newest *" #> <span>{listener.getCurrent}</span>
    } else {
      "#newest *" #> Noop
    }
  }`

Comment: SO doesn't format code in comments so its hard to make that out.  First to implement the method as def render = JsCmds.Noop and see if that has any effect.  If it doesn't, take a look at the requests & responses the page is making with something like Chrome Developer Tools or Wireshark.  Are the comet requests being made?  Are they receiving what looks like a valid response?

Comment: Sorry for the code formatting mess. I also tried `render` set to `JsCmds.Noop` but with no change whatsoever. I added some println statements and it seems like the CometActor isn't running resp. being started on the server at all. My println statements return nothing.

Comment: What is your production environment like?  Could their be some restriction on starting threads?  Have you tried a println where the comet actor is initialized or only when it receives a message?

Comment: My production environment is a Cubietruck (Cubieboard3) with Ubuntu 13.10 Linaro for ARM as OS and Java 8, Jetty 8. The wired thing is that I already deployed some very simple CometActors without any problems.

Comment: I've put println's where messages are received and the actor should be initialized but nothing gets printed out on the cubietruck. On my laptop I get `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in SBT from time to time while running the code. Maybe it's related. As I understand for every line in the log file a message is being send. Does that mean I have also a separate thread for every line created? Maybe that's too much for an ARM device? But I don't see or get any error. Just the page is blank and the jetty output contains no println.

Comment: The actor model is pretty efficient with thread usage.  It does *not* create a new thread for each message received.  I have no experience with JVM apps on ARM and I wonder if there could be some issue with that.  I'd suggest you post this to the group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb

Answer (score 0):

This line was causing the problem:

```
val tailer = Tailer.create(new java.io.File("/var/log/syslog"), listener)
```

On the server Jetty runs as user jetty which has no sufficient rights to read the file. Strange that I didn't get any "Permission denied" message or something. So, if I run Jetty as root my CometActor works well.

But running Jetty as root is considered dangerous. Here is a better solution:

```
sudo apt-get install acl
sudo setfacl -m u:jetty:r-x,g:adm:r-x /var/log/
sudo setfacl -m u:jetty:r--,g:adm:r-- /var/log/syslog
```